# ¿Existe una mejor forma de hacer este cuadrado con solo bordes?

Tags: java

Me tomó 20 minutos pensar en esta solución, pero es un código muy débil ya que si quisiera agrandar el cuadrado debería cambiar muchas variables y además, creo que es una mala práctica utilizar muchas sentencias If.
¿Que dicen ustedes?

**¿Cómo lo harían ustedes y qué le ven de malo a mi código?**

```
package exercises_two;

public class border_square {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int fila = 0; fila <= 3; fila++) {
            for (int columna = 0; columna <= 3; columna++) {
                if (fila == 0) {
                    System.out.print(columna);
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                if (fila == 1) {
                    if (columna == 0) {
                        System.out.print(columna);
                    }
                    System.out.print(" ");
                    if (columna ==3) {
                        System.out.print(" "+columna);
                    }
                }
                if (fila == 2) {
                    if (columna == 0) {
                        System.out.print(columna);
                    }
                    System.out.print(" ");
                    if (columna ==3) {
                        System.out.print(" "+columna);
                    }
                }
                if (fila == 3) {
                    System.out.print(columna);
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }

            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

El resultado debe ser este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Llego tarde... te dejo una solución que permite hacer rectángulos.

```
void crearRectangulo( int ancho, int alto ) {

     // recorremos una matriz virtual, fila a fila 
   for( int i = 0; i < alto; i++ ) {
      for( int j = 0; j < ancho; j++ ) {

          // si estamos en la primera fila, o en la última imprime el número de columna
        if( i == 0 || i == alto - 1 ) {
           System.out.print( j );
        }
        else {

             // si es la primer o última columna imprime el número de columna
           if( j == 0 || j == ancho - 1 ) {
              System.out.print( j );
           }
           else {

                // si no cumple las condiciones anteriores, imprime un espacio
              System.out.print( " " );
           }
        }

           // este sentencia es opcional, la puse para separar los números
         System.out.print( " " );
      }
        // agrega un salto de linea
      System.out.println( "" );          
   }
}
```

Se puede modificar para pasar del límite "9", agregando un **if** que imprima un espacio más si es menor que "10".

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero que debemos hacer es analizar en qué casos hay que pintar un número, y en este ejercicio es básicamente cuando estamos en los bordes. Eso está claro pero... por qué hardcodear los valores? Estaremos en los bordes siempre que uno de los valores de las variables en los bucles sea 0 o sea igual al límite de columnas/líneas que queremos pintar. Una vez determinado esto, podemos reducir el código y hacerlo "automático" de la siguiente manera:

```java
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* 
         * Prefiero usar constantes pues estos valores los usaremos en un par de sitios
         * y así solo los hay que cambiar una vez si queremos cambiar el cuadrado!
         */
        final int MAX_ROWS = 4;
        final int MAX_COLUMNS = 4;
        
        // Primer bucle - líneas
        for (int row = 0; row < MAX_ROWS; row++) {
            // Segundo bucle, columnas
            for (int column = 0; column < MAX_COLUMNS; column++) {
                if (row == 0 || row == MAX_ROWS - 1) { // Si estamos en la línea de arriba o la de abajo, pintamos el valor de la columna 
                    System.out.print(column);
                    System.out.print(" ");
                } else if (column == 0 || column == MAX_COLUMNS - 1) { // Si estamos en la primera o última columna, pintamos la columna actual
                    System.out.print(column);
                    System.out.print(" ");
                } else { // Si ninguna comprobación se cumple simplemente rellenamos con los espacios!
                    System.out.print(" ");
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            // Al terminar de iterar el segundo bucle imprimimos un salto de línea
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Te he dejado comentarios en el código explicándolo todo. Si pruebas a cambiar los valores de `MAX_ROWS` y `MAX_COLUMNS` verás que sigue funcionando sin cambiar nada más :)

Resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!!

Answer (score 1):

Dado que el problema es simple, puedes hacer unas asunciones:
Solo la primera y última fila van completas. Las filas intermedias, muestran un `0`, luego tantos espacios como hay de 1 a columnas - 1; y ponen el numero de columnas menos 1.

```
static void square(int rows, int cols) {
        for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
            if (row == 0 || row == rows - 1) {
                for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
                    System.out.print(col);
                    System.out.print("x");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.print(0);
                System.out.print(" ");
                int limit = cols - 1;
                for (int aux = 1; aux < limit; aux++) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                System.out.print(limit);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Solo puedes dibujar cuadros, y cuadros de menos de 10, antes que se descuadre.

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!!